# Spring Boot throws ClassNotFoundException with maven dependency for another project

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, spring-profiles, post-processing

I have Spring Boot project with simple `EnvironmentPostProcessor` implementation:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment;

public class DevProfilerResolverEnvironmentPostProcessor implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {

        @Override
        public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment configurableEnvironment, SpringApplication springApplication) {
            if (configurableEnvironment.getActiveProfiles().length == 0) {
                if (System.getenv().get("OS").contains("Windows")) {
                    configurableEnvironment.addActiveProfile("DEV");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, I registered this class to `sprig.factories`:

```
org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor = com.example.demo.DevProfilerResolverEnvironmentPostProcessor
```

Now structure looks like:

[image]

Snippet from pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

I executed with Maven:

> mvn install

Now I want to use this `EnvironmentPostProcessor` implementation on another spring boot project. Thus I added it to dependency section for the new project:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And I wrote simple service usage:

```
@Service
@Profile("DEV")
public class DeveloperService {

    @Scheduled(cron = "1/1 * * * * ?")
    public void doWork() {
        System.out.println("Developers.... ");
    }
}

and enabled scheduling for main class:

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class LvivBootApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LvivBootApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

However, I got following exception after main execution:

```
14:56:09.822 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to instantiate factory class: org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.demo.DevProfilerResolverEnvironmentPostProcessor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

and dependency is added to the new project:

[image]

I am running it exactly on Windows environment.

The idea is when OS is Windows add `DEV` profile for the first project.
Second has service which prints to console dummy info when the profile is `DEV` and scheduled this printing for every second.

**I can't find what is missed at this example?**

**SOLUTION:**

For making from first project library jar `pom` should be fixed like following:

```
<!--<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>-->
```

Or simple to eliminate this plugin from pom file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your first jar is not a library jar. It's a repackaged boot jar, created by the spring boot plugin, containing the first spring boot application and all its dependencies, intended to be executed, and not to be used as a library.

If you want to use that as a library, you need to use the non-repackaged jar file, containing only the classes and resources of the project.

It's quite bizarre to have an application depend on another application, though. You should create a library project, only containing common common classes and resources, and use that as a dependency to your two spring boot applications.

Comment: how to make first project jar library? Do I need to add additional configuration to pom file?

Comment: The same way you create any Maven project, but not using the spring boot plugin.

Comment: *.original jar file can be used as library which gets created with executable jar.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting because I had a similar error in similar circumstances - I searched for hours and the solution was very easy. I am using Eclipse for debugging - Eclipse doesn't use the produced jar from Maven build - it uses its own set of build paths with, as far as i understood, exploded classes etc.

My Maven project, the one that produced a JAR that I was including into my main project POM, didn't declare in any way some kind of dependency to the main project, e.g. via a common parent or whatever.

Eclipse seems to not understand that one of the dependencies I was using in the POM was a result of another local project - somehow, although the file (jar-with-dependencies) was in the Maven cache alright, it wasn't picking it up to copy to its own aforementioned set of classpath directories.

I needed to explicitly add it (my library project) into the main project via Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Projects - adding it to the list titled "Required projects on the build path:"